# On a server works on the other it does not. ¿API dll isn't registered? ErrNo: 80040154

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, api, 32bit-64bit, clearquest

I have installed on a 32bit server a IBM Rational ClearQuest and made a process which uses the api that they provide.
And there works perfectly.

When I migrate this to another server (64bit) it throws

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component 
>   with CLSID {94773112-72E8-11D0-A42E-00A024DED613} 
>   failed due to the following error: 80040154.

I went to the registry to see what was there, (in both servers) and in the first one, there were some keys regarding where this API dll is placed that in the 64bit server weren't. (Also there were a key about the framework)

I did a research on the web to see [this](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/braindump/chilkat_answers/com-clsid-error-80040154.html).

My options then (at least the only ones I could think of) where:

- Uninstall CQ and Reinstall it (Which I did and after some installation and uninstallation crashes of the product It was back up without any changes to my actual problem)
- Register the dlls I needed with regsrv32 (didn't work)
- Add the keys myself (also didn't work)

I've seen today this cscript, here [using Windows Script Host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2288634/684646) but it does not work with c#.

Supposely c# .Net2008 when the compiler says "Any" machine it clearly means both... but just in case I've changed it to 64bit exclusively...

And guess what... yes you are right... that didn't work also.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.-

---

Edit:

- InstallUtil on C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\v2.050727\ on the base dll didn't work
- asp_regiis (Which I've tried just in case) didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem was Windows Server 2008 UAT Protection

Searching on the web I've found that when I've tried to do a registration it was throwing error 5 Access Denied

#### This is the solution

Go to Control Panel --> User Accounts --> "Tune User Account Control on or off". Turn off "Use User Account Control (UAC) to help protect your computer", and restart the computer. Run "the process with the API" again and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you couldn't find the registry key is of course the source of the problem.  You are likely to find it back in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID, the home for 32-bit COM servers.  Assuming they are properly installed.

Which means that you cannot allow the jitter to generate 64-bit code.  A 64-bit process cannot execute any 32-bit code.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target = x86 is the simple fix.

Comment: I'll try that just now, I'll keep you posted =)

Comment: Still isn't working. What should I do afte compiling it and placing it on the issued server?

Comment: Well, as mentioned, you have to make sure that the COM server(s) you are using are properly installed.  Just copying your EXE isn't enough.  Did you find the key back yet?  You can use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to watch the app searching the registry.  Given that this is IBM stuff, I imagine some kind of licensing scheme needs to be observed.

Comment: The licence exceptions are covered and aren't an issue. Where's this ProcMon? does it come bydefault with Windows? or should I download the latest one on msdn? (I'm downloading it by the way). One of my guys is installing an IBM patch to see if that solves it. when he finishes I'll try following the exe sysinternal accessing with procmon. You will know the result ASAP. I have to wait until he finishes. So we don't screw the IBM CQ fussy patch installing. (*It is indeed fussy*).

Comment: I did the trace with the ProcMon... in fact I did it on both servers, the one that's currently working and the one that's not. The difference resides in a successful read of Rsaenh.dll [http://dll.paretologic.com/detail.php/rsaenh] (I don't know what has this specific dll to do here). While the OKServer after reading with different offsets goes to the actual API, the 64bit machine reads modifies the dll, deletes the dll, creates the dll, repeats this about 5 o 6 times and then goes to the rdp dll(dk why either). I've been told that the app works ok with 64bit, are they wrong?